# Tracking reading progress of documentations or ebooks

Tags: online-learning, learning, reading, learning-management-system

Challenge: I need to read a lot of documentations and websites, but often in random order. I need to track which articles of a website, or which pages of a documentation I already read. I want to mark pages as complete after reading, and read nothing twice.

So far I found no efficient tracking method. Copy-pasting urls to a text editor works for small sites, but with deep hierarchies it gets messy. For example, reading all [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en) would be hard to track because of it's deep hierarchy.

I highly appreciate any hints for Apps, Browser extensions or creative solutions.

Comment: Use your brain and remember them?

Answer (score 1):

If you read some page again, it presumably is because there are points you forgot/didn't get the first time around.

Who says you have to read *all* of it? Presumably you have some specific interest(s) in the subject matter, it is OK to just concentrate on the few documents that go to your points, work through them thoroughly, and at most skim over the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and programmed a Google Chrome Extension for my use case. It colors the links to the pages that are read.

https://github.com/synox/mark-as-done-extension

Answer (score 0):

Actually a simple spreadsheet seems adequate for what you want to do. A row for each publication with columns recording things of importance. Lots of room for comments and such, also.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to download everything you read as a PDF to a folder on your computer. Then use any PDF viewer that supports annotations/markup (e.g. [xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/)) to make a mark on pages/sections you have read.